# Tablix column formatting values

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, formatting, expression

I have a tablix with several columns. One of columns has discount percentage values. I want to change the font to white if all of the rows have value 0, and if some of the cells have different value, I want all the values to apperar black.

I have set the Font Color value to:

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!Discount.Value)=0, "White", "Black")
```

When all columns are 0, everything shows up white.

The problem is when some of the values are not 0, they show up black, but the 0 values are white and there are empty cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using this expression in the detail row of the **Tablix**, you might need to add a `Scope` paremeter to your `Sum` clause, something like:

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!Discount.Value, "DataSet1")=0, "White", "Black")
```

This is because the `Sum` will execute in the current `Scope` unless another is specified, so your expression will only consider the current row. Adding the scope as above will consider all rows in the **Dataset**.